# Link2019 C++ error

Tags: c++

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenGL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Application.cpp
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwCreateWindow referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwWindowShouldClose referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwPollEvents referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwMakeContextCurrent referenced in function _main
1>Application.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSwapBuffers referenced in function _main
1>D:\Visual Studio\_Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2015\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>D:\Visual Studio\_Projects\OpenGL\bin\Win32\Debug\OpenGL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenGL.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I was importing some code and was linking it and all other things you gotta do, but when i finished, it still had these errors... could someone help me?

Comment: `1>D:\Visual Studio\_Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\Dependencies\GLFW\lib-vc2015\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'` this error seems quite clear to me.

Comment: Your glf library must match the same architecture of your target application.

Comment: and how to i do that? @Asesh

Comment: @Rohan if you are developing 32-bit apps then all those libraries must be 32-bit too. The same rules applies for 64-bit apps too